# Entity Framework one-to-many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two simple classes:

```
class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int IndeksNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List <Student > Students { get; set; }
}
```

Database is created correctly (using Code First). I have added couple items to both tables, but all the time Students list and Group property in Student are null. I have no idea why. I have searched solution for about an hour and i came up with something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasRequired(st => st.Group)
    .WithMany(gr => gr.Students)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But it doesn't help. I have no idea what may went wrong or why Group.Students and Student.Group are always null. List of groups and list of students are selected from db successfully - i mean all params except those connections.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the [Lazy Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232) feature of EntityFramework. Your navigation property must be virtual. In your `Student` class in the the case. The problem is with your `Group` class. The navigational property is a virtual `List<Student>` it must be a `virtual ICollection<Student>`

You can simply change your `Group` to

```
class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student > Students { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: By navigation property in Student class you mean foreign key to Group (GroupId)?

Comment: Yes, the Student class is ok, no problem with it

Comment: Could you post an example of code when you get data from the database? Is it possible that you are detaching the entity before retrieving the Students?

Comment: I have fixed my problem by using dbcontext.Students.Include("Group").ToList() (added Include)

Comment: With a `virtual ICollection<T>` `Include()` isn't mandatory. Using the `Include()` is called **Eager loading** and this is needed only if you are detaching your student entity before retrieving the groups

Comment: What means detaching entity before retrieving the groups? I'm getting students with dbContext.Students.ToList(). That's all

Comment: After that, when are you accessing the student.Groups? Is the `student` still attached to the dataContext? Can you post then code from context.students.ToList() to student.Groups